# Is "suggest that -- do not" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

You ask, does “other than” in § 188.606(f) suggest that variations in the material of a closure for the cover of a UN11A steel drum do not constitute a different packaging design type for which design qualification and periodic testing is required.

If I remove the **words** as shown below, it seems correct:

You ask, does “other than” in § 188.606(f) suggest that variations **(in the material of a closure for the cover of a UN11A steel drum)** do not constitute a different packaging design type for which design qualification and periodic testing is required.

Comment: suggest that variations (blah blah) not constitute: the "do not" is too not needed. Also: are required. This is basically proofing. But I can't help myself. A simpler sentence so you can see it: We suggested that the questions not be so complicated.

Comment: The information you suggest removing isn't affecting anything. But, honestly, the sentence is so long that by the time I get to the end of it, I've mostly forgotten how it started or what it's talking about. If I were tasked with actually proofreading this, I would simplify it right away.

Comment: You need a question mark for your audience member's question, and, correctly, you should use quotation marks. The American standard is: // You ask, "does 'other than' in in § 188.606(f)  ... testing is required?" //  The British standard reverses the types of quotation marks: // 'does "other than" ... ?' //

By the way, thanks for the Accept. It was what finally allowed me to comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Suggested that" is not related to "do/does". Your answer can be found in this question: "what do or does?"

Variations do. (If it were singular, it would be "variation does".)